# Laptop not resuming after suspend

Tags: 15.10, suspend, power-management, resume

Today, I got a couple updates to my laptop running Ubuntu 15.10.

[image: updates installed image]

Now when I suspend my laptop either with the suspend button or by closing the lid, it doesn't resume after I open the lid or touch the keyboard. It turns on as if it was shut down. This didn't happen before today's updates. Has this happened to anyone else? What troubleshooting steps can I take to diagnose it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  It was working just fine.  Got some updates yesterday as well and now it won't recover from suspend.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one, wish I knew how to fix it though :(

Comment: It finally got to me so with no other alternatives presenting themselves, I ended up reinstalling 15.10 from scratch.  Seems to have worked so far.  After updating all packages to their latest version it still seems to be capable to resume from suspend.

Comment: Damn, I really gotta back mine up before doing that. It is getting very annoying though.